# Two definitions of conditional cumulative distribution function. Why are they equivalent?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

I quote definition of conditional cumulative distribution function (for two random variables $X$ and $Y$) from two different sources ($F$ denotes c.d.f. while $f$ denotes p.d.f.).

1. $P\left[X\leq x| Y\in\left(y, y+dy\right)\right]=\dfrac{\left[F\left(x,y+dy\right)-F(x,y)\right]/dy}{\left[F_Y\left(y+dy\right)-F_Y(y)\right]/dy}\hspace{0.5cm}\stackrel{dy\rightarrow0}\rightarrow\hspace{0.5cm}\dfrac{\partial{F(x,y)/\partial{y}}}{f_Y(y)}$;
2. $P\left[X\leq x| Y\in\left(y, y+dy\right)\right]=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{u=-\infty}^{x}f(u,y)dudy}{f_Y(y)dy}=\displaystyle\int_{u=-\infty}^{x}\dfrac{f(u,y)du}{f_Y(y)}$

My **question** is: *why $\dfrac{\partial{F(x,y)/\partial{y}}}{f_Y(y)}=\displaystyle\int_{u=-\infty}^{x}\dfrac{f(u,y)du}{f_Y(y)}$?*

Comment: So what should $F$ be exactly? You write like $f$'s the density of the joint distribution $(X,Y)$, but there is no canonical analogue of a CDF for higher dimensional distributions.

Comment: I confirm that $f(X,Y)$ is the density of joint distribution $(X,Y)$ , while $F(X,Y)$ is CDF of the joint distribution $(X,Y)$. Are you telling that $F(X,Y)$ cannot be defined? Above I have just quoted definitions from two different sources. Would you say that the first one is not correct? @WoolierThanThou

Comment: Well... what would should the function be? Should it hold that $F(x,y)=P[X\leq x,Y\leq y]$? I'm not saying you can't define a cumulative distribution function of a joint variable, but it won't inherit the properties of the one-dimensional CDF (It doesn't seem to me, for instance, that the above function completely determines the distribution of $(X,Y)$).

Comment: Yes, it should hold that $F(x,y)=P[X\leq x, Y\leq y]$ as you have just said @WoolierThanThou

Comment: You're gonna need the pdf to have a certain level of regularity, but at that point, just try writing up how $F(x,y+\varepsilon)-F(x,y)$ looks. You might want to draw some inspiration from the usual proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Yeah, ok...but, let us assume that the first definition can be correct. Given this, is it perfectly equal to the second one? If so, why? @WoolierThanThou

Comment: I was: I'm saying, if you just assume that the pdf is sufficiently nice, so that you can perform operations naïvely, then, since $F(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^y\int_{-\infty}^x f(u,v)\textrm{d}u\textrm{d}v$, you can prove equality simply by following the usual proof of the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Sorry :( Thank you a lot for helping me

Comment: No sweat. I get that my phrasing might have come off confusing.